# Limit of the minimum value of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Let $$f(a)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}|ax^n-1|dx+\frac{1}{2}$$ Here $n$ is a natural number. Let $b_n$ be the minimum value of $f(a)$ for $a>1$. Evaluate $$\lim_{m \to \infty}b_mb_{m+1}\ldots b_{2m}$$

Some starters please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}f(a) = \frac{a}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\left| x^n-\frac{1}{a}\right|\,dx+\frac{1}{2}&=&\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(x^n-1/a)\,dx+a\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a}}}\left(\frac{1}{a}-x^n\right)\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt[n]{a}}\\&=&\frac{a}{2n+2}+\frac{n}{(n+1)\sqrt[n]{a}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
attains its minimum at $a=2^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$:
$$ b_n = 2^{-\frac{1}{n+1}}.$$
Then consider that:
$$ \sum_{k=m}^{2m}\frac{1}{k+1}\stackrel{m\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\log 2.$$

Comment: Could you check the limits of your first integral on RHS?

Comment: @User1upon0: they are right. If $f(x)$ is negative on $(0,a)\subset [0,1]$ and positive over $(a,1)$, $$\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx + 2 \int_{0}^{a}(-f(x))\,dx. $$